# Selenium python plugin and permission issues

Tags: python, selenium, security, cookies, plugins

I am using python and Selenium for a project.

But I am stuck trying to open a web page.

To access this page you require to authenticate and then press a usb device for second factor authentication, but only one time for each browser session.

I always get the page "you did not present a posture cookie. please install or repair your AEA plugin"

Comparing a manual browser it seems to have the plugin.

I have tried the following:

1)Tried by authenticating manually and then saving the browser cookies.

2)I have also tried by adding chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\Users\"+username+"\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default") that is apparently where cookies are stored but both method fails.

3. I found the plugin ID, packed the plugin and tried to add the extension to the webdriver, but got the error "Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator."

Is there any way to make the os thing that I browsing manually? By searching I fund that the option options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false); used to work on previous chrome webdriver versions, but is not working anymore, and disabling all plugins does not seem to be an option here.

Any advice would be appreciated.